# JavaFX NoClassDefFoundError zap plugin Browser View

Tags: java, javafx, zap

I want to use the Browser View Plugin for Owasp Zap, but getting the following error:

```
19529 [ZAP-BootstrapGUI] WARN  org.zaproxy.zap.extension.browserView.ExtensionHttpPanelBrowserView - Unable to use JavaFX:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
```

I have `openjfx`, `openjfx-source`, `libopenjfx-jni`, `libopenjfx-java`, `libcontrolsfx-java` and `libeasybind-java` installed. I also have tried it with openjdk8 and 14.
My system is Ubuntu 20.10, but I also get the same error when I use the machines from [tryhackme](https://tryhackme.com).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order yo use the Browser view add-on you have to install JavaFX.

`sudo apt install openjfx` for Ubuntu.

You may also need to set the jfx path (https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx):
`export PATH_TO_FX=path/to/javafx/lib`

Per: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/6339#issuecomment-758173453, you may also need to start ZAP as follows (or edit the shell script to do the same):
`$ java --module-path /usr/share/openjfx/lib/ --add-modules javafx.swing,javafx.web zap.jar`

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help and I also started zap with the last command in your link

Comment: Answer updated with details from Zap's issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks it works, just added it in the zap.sh script and it works normally

Comment: Thanks for confirming!